# Sargable version of DateDiff() SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've inherited some C# application code that has a fluent SQL query builder which is used across our code base.  Some of the more common queries apply filters like "Date on or after today".  These filters are stored in a SQL table as metadata for the query builder and whilst investigating performance and deadlock issues I've realised that these query components are not sargable.

A typical query built by this builder looks like:

```
DECLARE @systemDate DATETIME
SET @systemDate = [dbo].GetSystemDate()

SELECT [table1].* FROM [dbo].[XXX] AS [table1]
WHERE ... AND DateDiff(d, @systemDate, [table1].PaymentDate) <= 0 
AND ...
```

The column PaymentDate is stored as a datetime, with a time component.
GetSystemDate() returns a datetime at midnight - i.e. 2017-10-18 00:00:00.000

The problem is that even if I have PaymentDate in a covering index SQL Server can't do a seek on it as it's in the DateDiff() function.  However, the design of the query builder makes it very easy for me to substitute in a more efficient, sargable expression that would be applied for all constructed SQL queries.

What would be an equivalent sargable query for the following given that time components are also in play on the queried column and the resulting query would need to return identical results to the existing DateDiff() calls?  I've seen other solutions around that use DateAdd() and comparisons but I'm wary of these behaving differently given that there's a time component in our data.

```
OperatorDisplayName   OperatorExpression   ValueExpression   ColumnExpression
Today                        =                  0           DateDiff(d, @systemDate, {0})
This Week                    =                  0           DateDiff(ww, @systemDate, {0})
Last Week                    =                 -1           DateDiff(ww, @systemDate, {0})
This Month                   =                  0           DateDiff(m, @systemDate, {0})
Last Month                   =                 -1           DateDiff(m, @systemDate, {0})
On or Before Today          <=                  0           DateDiff(d, @systemDate, {0})
On or After Today           >=                  0           DateDiff(d, @systemDate, {0})
Before Today                 <                  0           DateDiff(d, @systemDate, {0})
After Today                  >                  0           DateDiff(d, @systemDate, {0})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `@systemDate` doesn't have a time component, you can build >= < comparisons:

```
OperatorDisplayName   OperatorExpression   ValueExpression   ColumnExpression
Today                        =                  0           {0} >= @systemDate AND {0} < DATEADD(d, 1, @systemDate)
```

You don't really use the Operator or Value this way, since it's built into the column expression.

The week and month operators will get more complicated because your expressions will need to include code to calculate the first day of the week/month based on `@systemDate`, but there are samples of this already on the web.